# Output is not fully displayed on terminal of visual studio code when using "run code" function

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I run the python file with "run code" mode, the output is not fully displayed in the terminal, but when I run the python file with "run python file" mode, the output is fully displayed.

I have set the terminal Integrated scrollback to a much higher number but that didn't fix it. I'm speculating this error is caused by the code runner extension. Hope someone can understand and solve this problem for me.